# Get elements by size

Tags: javascript, dom, xpath

I have to get all the elements in an HTML page having size 300x250 (just the parent though. So if a DIV is 300x250 and has an image inside of the same dimension I shall get just the div).

I can't use jQuery or other frameworks like that and the ways I thought are these:

1. looping all the elements in a page checking their dimensions (bad bad. Don't like it)
2. using XPath (is there a way to filter by width and height by XPath?)

Do you guys know a better way to do it?

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/ ???

Answer (score 2):

You haven't said which `width` or `height` you are interested in. Of course if there are `img` elements with `width` or `height` attributes in the document then XPath can select them (e.g. `//img[@width = '300' and @height = '250']`). But container elements like `div` elements don't have such attributes and usually you access their `offsetWidth`/`offsetHeight` DOM properties. As far as I know such properties can't be accessed within an XPath expression so XPath could only help to select certain elements and then you need to access the `offsetWidth`/`offsetHeight` properties of any DOM elements nodes returned by an XPath evaluation. So this answer is mainly about your XPath request.

Depending on target browsers you might be able to use a `TreeWalker` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/treeWalker.filter or `NodeIterator` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeIterator.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to loop through all elements on the page (e.g. `querySelectorAll('*')`). Indeed, given your requirement that you want the first ancestor node with the correct size, it would be harder to do so.

However, @MartinHonnen is correct: there is no way to extract the `offsetHeight` of a `<div>` or other flexible-size element with XPath. You must walk through the elements and test them.

I'd do it using a breadth-first or depth-first traversal that prunes a branch when it is either found to be the correct size, or when the size has become either too narrow or too short. This should improve your performance dramatically.

Here's a sketch of code (untested):

```js
function findElementsBySize(w,h){
  var found = [];
  recursiveFind(document.body);
  return found;

  function recursiveFind(el){
    if (el.offsetWidth==w && el.offsetHeight==h){
      found.push(el);
    } else if (el.offsetWidth>=w && el.offsetHeight>=h){
      for (var i=el.childNodes.length;i--;){
        recursiveFind(el.childNodes[i]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```